How to close up this barn attic from birds and carpenter bees? Exposed joists and open soffits
There's an old barn, neglected for well over 3 years, used to be for livestock. Only used for farm storage for now (hay, tools and equipment), but it's getting full of bird nests, bird poop piles, and carpenter bees are starting to punch a worrying amount of holes in edges of rafters (and that's just where I can easily see!) I am closing the barn up - shuttering or screening windows, replacing doors. An area I'm unsure of is closing up the attic/soffits, especially around an overhang.
For carpenter bees, I plan to whitewash the joists and attic plywood floor. I hear they don't like drilling in white objects. But the soffits let in birds and bees to the attic, so I need to plug those up. Given the way joists, rafters, and plywood are DIY'd by past owner, I'm not sure how to efficiently and effectively plug those up.
Here are 9 photos of what I'm working with. I want to seal the attic off, the barn interior off, and leave myself with a paintable surface to keep carpenter bees from damaging rafters and joists. Thinking to somehow plug with wood, hardware cloth, insulation or what. You'll see some gaps above cinderblock walls going into the barn, between attic joists, are plugged with insulation from past owner. This structure is about 40 years old.









Those last 4 images really highlight where I need to plug:

Above barn cinderblock wall, below attic plywood floor, between the attic joists.

At the edge of the attic, either blocking off the gap into attic, covering the soffit somehow, and/or covering gaps between attic joists and soffit opening.



Just take some mosquito net and staple it. It will still allow ventilation.

For the bees, a facebook friend who used to work for pest extermers suggests a paper bag tied up with newspaper/small bags inside.  The bees think it is a wasp nest and stay away.

Mosquito or bird net is a good idea. I was thinking rigid hardware cloth and that's how I closed off some windows. More flexible material stapled up for the more complex edges could work.

Still, how would I close this up more permanently if I wanted to, as a step toward cleaning up the barn interior?
